# Как сделать две формы в одном экшне ? Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

День добрый, меня зовут Дмитрий, и мне нужна ваша помощь) Мне нужно реализовать админку, где можно будет редактировать записи и удалять. Все я решил реализовать на одной странице( так нужно) . Так вот , когда я жму на submit кнопку формы добавления, то оно автоматически добавляет и редактирует сообщение, если жму на редактирование , то оно редактирует и добавляет сразу же. Как избавиться от дубляжа? 
Вот мой контроллер

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = Worker::find()->with('jobPositionIdF')->orderBy('worker_id');
    $worker_ins = new Worker();
    $worker_update=Worker::findOne(2);
    $pages=new Pagination(['totalCount'=>$query->count(),'pageSize'=>8]);
    $worker_position=$query->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();


        if ($worker_ins->load(\Yii::$app->request->post('button1')))
        {

            if ($worker_ins->save())
            {

                echo \Yii::$app->session->SetFlash('succes', 'Данные приняты');
                $this->refresh();
            } else
                {
                \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Ошибка');
                }
        }

   if ($worker_update->load(\Yii::$app->request->post('button2'))){


        if ($worker_update->save())
        {
            echo \Yii::$app->session->SetFlash('succes', 'Данные приняты');
            $this->refresh();
        } else
        {
            \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Ошибка');
        }
    }
   return $this->render('index', ['worker_position' => $worker_position,'worker_ins'=>$worker_ins,'pages'=>$pages,'worker_update'=>$worker_update]);}
```

`
Вьюшка  - Форма 1.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'form1']); ?>
    <?php echo $form->field($worker_ins,'full_name');?>
    <?php echo $form->field($worker_ins,'job_position_id_f')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(app\models\JobsPosition::find()->all(), 'jobs_position_id', 'position')) ?>
    <?php echo $form->field($worker_ins,'adress');?>
    <?php echo $form->field($worker_ins,'rent_price');?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['name' => 'button1','class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
```

Форма 2 -

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'form2']); ?>
        <?php echo $form->field($worker_update,'full_name');?>
        <?php echo $form->field($worker_update,'job_position_id_f')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(app\models\JobsPosition::find()->all(), 'jobs_position_id', 'position')) ?>
        <?php echo $form->field($worker_update,'adress');?>
        <?php echo $form->field($worker_update,'rent_price');?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','name' => 'button2']) ?>
        </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Если я добавляю условие, как написано в контролере по имени submita, то не работает вообще ничего(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доброе утро.

Я думаю, что проблема у Вас из-за этих условий

```
if ($worker_ins->load(\Yii::$app->request->post('button1')))
// and
if ($worker_update->load(\Yii::$app->request->post('button2'))){
```

Вы проверяете присутствие индекса в $_POST запросе, но не проверяете чему он равен. Поэтому у Вас и создаёт запись и редактирует.
Попробуйте сделать так

```
// для кнопки добавить параметр value и задать значение
<?= Html::submitButton('Отправить',
                       ['class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                        'name' => 'button1',
                        'value' => 'create']) ?>
    </div>

// в контроллере проверить это значение
if ($worker_update->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())
    && \Yii::$app->request->post('button1') == 'create'){
```

Точно так же сделайте и для второй кнопки. Тогда в действии контроллера Вы сможете отличить создание записи от обновления.
Но я бы сделал два разных действия, отдельно для создания записи, отдельно для редактирования. В форме, при помощи js/jquery проверял бы, по какой кнопке click-нули и в зависимости от этого подставлял бы нужное значение для action формы. Форма будет отправляться на два разных адреса. Легче будет работать с этими действиями контроллера, не будет свалки кода в них.

p.s. Можно добавить параметры для любой из кнопок ActionColumn, или добавить свою кнопку

```
'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'action-column'],
'template' => '{view} {update} {delete}',
'buttons' => [
   'update' => function($name, $model, $key){
     return Html::a('<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                    ['update', 'id' => $model->id],
                    [
                        'style' => 'color: red',
                        'title' => 'обновить запись',
                        'data' => [
                            'method' => 'post',
                            'params' => '{"id_s": ' . $model->id .',"id_c": ' .$model->relation->id . '}'
                        ]
                    ]
                   );
        }
]
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, сработало. Попробую может и по другому сделать. Пока навыки слабы. Если вам не сложно, то  вы не могли бы мне подсказать еще одно. У меня есть кнопка - изменить, возле каждой строки таблицы. Я хочу, чтобы в запрос, где происходить изменение - передавалось значение Id из формы,а не статично, как задал я. Я видел вариант , чтобы передавать через Url , но т.к все делаю на одной странице, то такой вариант не работает.

Comment: И если вариант - через скрытое поле формы, то как в yii2 передать в конструктор данные ? Просто пока у меня нет других идей(

Comment: Обновил ответ. Самый простой вариант. Через свойство button Вы можете изменить любую кнопку в ActionColumn. Подробней смотрите в документации https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn

Comment: Круто конечно, а если при нажатии на кнопку - сплывает модальное окно - в котором содержится   - id записи. Можно как то в свойствах modal виджета так указать и принять с контроллера?

Comment: Всё можно, было бы желание)))

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку передаёте через js/jquery id записи, action для формы в модальном окне, дополнительные параметры и ещё кучу всего, что пожелаете)))

Comment: Благодарю! Желание есть) Нужно сдать уже скоро) Знаю, что если уже это сделаю и так же удаление записей, то - дело в шляпе))

Comment: тогда отмечайте решением

Comment: удаление делаете так же как обновление, в buttons, повторю, можно переопределить всё кнопки, а так же создать новые, свои.

Comment: Я хочу - через модальное окно попробовать обновление. Так как заполнение я так же делаю.